# Undeclared Identifier Error when Compiling Solidity Contract

Tags: solidity

When compiling this contract I receive an undeclared identifier error for

> balances[address]

Here is the code.  Not sure how to add a further identifier for the address.

```
contract Eagle {

    address wife = address(0);
    address husband = address(1);
    address payable owner; 

    constructor() public{
        owner = payable(msg.sender);
    }

    function withdraw() public {
        uint amount = balances[msg.sender];
        balances[msg.sender] = 0;
        owner.transfer(amount);
    }

    receive () payable {
        balances[wife] += msg.value / 2;
        balances[husband] += msg.value / 2; 
    }

    function getBalance() public view returns(uint _wife) {
        return balances[wife];
    }

}
```

Comment: Which line is throwing you this error?

Comment: Every line that uses the balances[address] method. 

balances[wife] 
balances[husband]
balances[msg.sender] etc...

Comment: Actually, the mapping for balances was never created and your contract is not inheriting from any other contract. That may be causing the error.

Comment: that solved it - thank you!